# I'm having problems setting text dynamically with Python and Kivy

Tags: kivy

I am trying to teach myself Kivy with a little project, I really don't understand why this isn't working. I have used very similar code (identical but not in scroll view) in other spots in my code without trouble but here it is throwing up an error message.

Here is my python code:

```
class FeedbackWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.moves = ""
        for move in dance[0]:
            self.moves += move + "\n"
        self.ids.movelist_label.text = self.moves  # Set the text dynamically
```

Here is my Kivy code:

```
<FeedbackWindow>:
    name: "feedbackWindow"
    movelist_label: movelist_label
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            pos_hint: {"right":1,"top":1}
            size_hint: 0.1,0.1
            text: "X"
            id: home
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "mainWindow"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False
            do_scroll_y: True
            size_hint: .4,1
            #pos_hint: {"x_center":.5}
            halign: 'center'
            Label:
                id: movelist_label  # Give the label a unique id
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '48sp'
                text: "Temp text"
```

Here is my error message

> File "h:\IT\Kivy\flashing.py", line 135, in **init**
> self.ids.movelist_label.text = self.moves  # Set the text dynamically    File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in
> kivy.properties.ObservableDict.**getattr**  AttributeError: 'super'
> object has no attribute '**getattr**'

I've tried referencing my python text from in my kivy file by replacing
`text: "Temp text`
with
'text: self.moves'
which gave an error message
and with
'text: root.moves'
which ran but had no text

Comment: Likely that the `ids` are not yet set up when you `__init__()` method is run. Try moving that out out of the `__init__()` method and calling it with `Clock.schedule_once()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution,

text: self.moves

was working, but something was stuffing up the positioning so it was printing off the screen.

Cheers